# htaccess - Redirects with more than 1 level deep not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite, godaddy

Just moved to shared hosting on GoDaddy and Im trying to get my .htaccess rules working.

Heres what I have:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^view/(\w+)$ viewitem.php?itemid=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/(\w+)$ viewcategory.php?tag=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^faq$ faq.php
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^submit$ submit.php
RewriteRule ^contactmsg$ handler-contact.php
```

All the pages @ the root of the domain seem to be working i.e mydomain.org/faq, mydomain.org/about are working.

But whenever I try mydomain.org/category/somecategory, I get a 404. How can I fix my .htaccess to obey these rules that are more than 1 level deep?

Thanks,

**EDIT: I have fixed the rules by changing them to the following:**

```
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$ viewitem.php?itemid=$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ viewcategory.php?tag=$1
```

**Can anyone confirm/deny that this is the *proper* way to fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new way you're doing it (with `(.*)`) is correct.

Comment: Ok cool. Thats just a wildcard for everything Im assuming? What did (\w+) technically do before?

Comment: `.*` means match anything.  Specifically, `.` means "any character", and the `*` means 0 or more of those.  `\w`in perl-compatible regexes (which Apache should use there) means alphanumeric or "_".  So, maybe your categories have some other character in them?  Spaces?

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the clarification Bill. Categories dont have spaces, dont know why they wouldnt be caught there.

Comment: What does a category look like?  Can you show the logs from one?

Comment: A category is just a string with no spaces - e.g. "friends", "family", "misc", "health". Any ideas?

Comment: From some googling around, I see that `^view/([\w]+)$` might work for you.  Give it a shot?  I don't know why you would need to put `[]` around the character class...

Comment: Your latest comment didnt work, I think ill just stick to (.*)$